# intelisense not showing object and function links

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

my **VSC** intelisense is not showing the **sugestions** for **react** and **react-native** components. when i'm typing, **the sugestions all appear as text, not objects or functions**.
But for my own builtin imports and my libraries its working
Here are three screenshots representing the problem (the last one is a SS of how it would be working as intended):

[image]

[image]

[image: in this image its working as intended]

Comment: react native 0.65 and 0.64 versions tested